# Adobe XI Run an action skip password protected files

Tags: adobe, acrobat

I am trying to batch process PDF files using 'Action Wizard' using Adobe Acrobat Xi Pro. How do I skip the password protected files and ignore error files? The help document says 'Do Not Ask For Password' but I couldn't find it. Any help would be appreciated.

https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/action-wizard-acrobat-pro.html#automate_password_entr%20y_for_actions

Answer (score 0):

I found it in

**Acrobat/Reader>click Edit menu (in the top left corner)>then click Preferences>Action Wizard**